# modular arthmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, logarithms, fermat-numbers

To prove that a number p is prime we use this formula $a^{p-1} \pmod p = 1$

In the case of high powers can we derive a formula to solve higher power orders:
$a^{p-1} \pmod p = 1$

$(a^{p-2}) (p-1) \pmod p = 1$

taking log to both sides we get:
$\log\left(\left(a^{p-2}\right)(p-1)\pmod p\right) = \log(1)$

From the property $\log(uv) = \log (u ) + \log(v)$, we get:

$\log(a^{p-2})+\log(p-1 \pmod p) = \log 1$

From another property of log : $\log(a^n) = n \log a $

we have
$(p-2) \log(a)+\log(p-1)=\log 1 $

wheres the part that has gone wrong here?
why is it not mathematically true?

Comment: This is hard to read.

Comment: It is hard to show that a number, $n$, is prime by using $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.  See [Carmichael Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).  i didn't try to read any further.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: First, your notation is incorrect. It should be $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ instead of $a^{p-1}\pmod p=1$. Second, while it is true that given a prime $p$ then for any integer $a$,$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, the converse is not true. Third, going from $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ to $a^{p-2}(p-1)\equiv1\pmod p$ is incorrect. Fourth, how are you defining $\log$? Depending on the base you use, $\log$ may or may not be defined for all numbers in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Finally, you seemed to have lost $\pmod p$ somewhere.

Comment: @Kyky Without wanting to be pedantic, $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ is true if $p$ is prime and does not divide $a$. But an excellent comment collecting the many issues.

Comment: @Peter I think you might have misunderstood me. As I've said above if $p$ is prime then $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, but my point was that the converse (if $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ then $p$ is prime) is false (See lulu's comment). OP claimed that the converse was true in the first sentence.

Comment: I only wanted to point out that $p$ is not allowed to be a divisor of $a$ to have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$. I understood the post.

Comment: The condition $p\nmid a$ is missing. If $p\mid a$, we do not have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$

Answer (score 1):

The primality tests in regular use (e.g. [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)) are different from this Fermat test (which can be fooled, but rarely; practical primality tests use the Fermat test to weed out composites as a first step).

To compute $a^n$ for large $n$ a practical solution is to use [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring):

$\begin{align*}
   a^{2 k}
     &= (a^k)^2 \\
   a^{2 k + 1}
     &= (a^k)^2 \cdot a
\end{align*}$

Computing $a^n$ is not *that* expensive.

To use logarithms (you need the *exact* power!) you'd need to compute $\log a$ and then $10^{n \log a}$ to a lot of significant figures, much more than is practical.